# Limit DropDownList selection to only one of that value in GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my ASP `GridView control`, I have a `column` with a `sort order dropdownlist`.
  The `gridview` contains several `dozen rows`.
  There are four values in every `dropdownlist` (1,2,3,4).
  The idea is, only one row in the `grid` can have a sort order of 1, only one row can have a sort order of 2, etc.

If a row already has a sort order of 1 selected in the `dropdownlist`, and I select a value of 1 in another row, I want all other rows with a value of 1 to reset to the first (empty) `listitem` in the `dropdown list`.

Comment: how many records are there on a page 4 I guess? If not what will happen to other rows of your gridview drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more detailed and at least let us know what code you are using. In VB I believe it would look something like this:

```
Sub list1_changed(byval sender as object, byval e as eventargs) handles list1.selection_changed

dim i as integer
if list1.selectedvalue = 1 then
   if list2.selectedvalue = 1 then
     list2.selectedindex = 0
   end if
   if list3.selectedvalue = 1 then
     list2.selectedindex = 0
   end if
   if list3.selectedvalue = 1 then
     list2.selectedindex = 0
   end if 
end if

end sub
```

I just free-handed that so you'll have to double check the properties, spelling, etc. of course. It's really just basic logic. When one dropdownlist is changed, cycle through the remaining ones and check if they equal 1, if so switch them to the first index item (the empty one). You'd have to repeat that subroutine for each dropdownlist of course. Good luck!